# Weather Underground API is returning JSON with formatting characters (lots of \n\t and such). Is there any way to get unformatted JSON from them?

Tags: json, getjson, weather-api

This is the response I get from Weather Underground:

```
"\n{\n  \"response\": {\n  \"version\":\"0.1\",\n  \"termsofService\":\"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html\",\n  \"features\": {\n  \"geolookup\": 1\n  }\n\t}\n\t\t,\t\"location\": {\n\t\t\"type\":\"INTLCITY\",\n\t\t\"country\":\"EG\",\n\t\t\"country_iso3166\":\"EG\",\n\t\t\"country_name\":\"Egypt\",\n\t\t\"state\":\"\",\n\t\t\"city\":\"Wadi El Natroon\",\n\t\t\"tz_short\":\"EET\",\n\t\t\"tz_long\":\"Africa/Cairo\",\n\t\t\"lat\":\"30.000000\",\n\t\t\"lon\":\"30.000000\",\n\t\t\"zip\":\"00000\",\n\t\t\"magic\":\"1\",\n\t\t\"wmo\":\"62357\",\n\t\t\"l\":\"/q/zmw:00000.1.62357\",\n\t\t\"requesturl\":\"global/stations/62357.html\",\n\t\t\"wuiurl\":\"http://www.wunderground.com/global/stations/62357.html\",\n\t\t\"nearby_weather_stations\": {\n\t\t\"airport\": {\n\t\t\"station\": [\n\t\t{ \"city\":\"Wadi El Natroon\", \"state\":\"\", \"country\":\"Egypt\", \"icao\":\"\", \"lat\":\"30.40250015\", \"lon\":\"30.36333275\" }\n\t\t,{ \"city\":\"Alexandria Borg El Arab\", \"state\":\"\", \"country\":\"EG\", \"icao\":\"HEBA\", \"lat\":\"30.91769981\", \"lon\":\"29.69639969\" }\n\t\t,{ \"city\":\"Alexandria\", \"state\":\"\", \"country\":\"EG\", \"icao\":\"HEAX\", \"lat\":\"31.18166733\", \"lon\":\"29.94638824\" }\n\t\t]\n\t\t}\n\t\t,\n\t\t\"pws\": {\n\t\t\"station\": [\n\t\t]\n\t\t}\n\t\t}\n\t}\n}\n"
```

As you can see there are a bunch of characters that aren't supposed to be there. Is there a different query to get unformatted JSON or do I have to parse all this garbage out before handing it off to a JSON parser? Am I in some sort of debug mode or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the Restful for web services and you encoding the array in Json if you using the rest don't do encoding it's working by default in Json.

Comment: or i think you encoding the Json 2nd time.

Answer (score 0):

The newline (\n) and tab (\t) characters are probably listed by your debugger while the actual response contains formatted data (so the newlines display as an actual newline). This would not pose any problem to a JSON parser, just feed the data to it.

Answer (score 0):

Oops.. It was a Gson issue (or an issue with my use of Gson), not a Weather Underground issue. Need to use:

```
val jsonObj = JsonParser().parse(it).asJsonObject
```

Instead of:

```
val jsonObj = gson.toJsonTree(it)
```

It is the JSON string. Code is in Kotlin.